# Uncaught CurlException: 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to graph.facebook.com:443

Tags: php, facebook, exception, curl, ssl

I keep getting this error, and it seems like it has appeared out of nowhere. I've been working at my project for some weeks, and this didn't show up until now.

When I try to run my app on `localhost`, the error in the title is shown. I have tried adding `$opts[CURLOPT_SSLVERSION] = 3;` in `base_facebook.php` as specified in another post, but it didn't work. I really have no idea what should I do now. Can anyone give me a helping hand?

Answer (score 0):

change registry values: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL2.0\Client
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000(0)